# Install Python Library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to import win32com in python
Then I import using

1. pip install pypiwin32
2. pip install pywin32
3. python -m pip install pypiwin32
4. python -m pip install pywin32

But, there is no success and get error notification

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pypiwin32 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-xfjlulo3/pypiwin32_de338b78d1fd4e1a9fecfba7f7b126e9/setup.py", line 121
          print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
                                 ^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

Please help

Comment: what version of python have you installed?

Answer (score 2):

Tackling your error message, originating from `pip install pypiwin32`:

```
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
```

shows that you are trying to install a module written for python 2x using a python 3x version, which will not work.

There are versions of `pypiwin32` or `pywin32`that support python 3x, but not for your OS. You are trying to get a windows specific python module on a non-windows machine. If you look at [the pypi page of pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) we see in the description

> provides access to many of the Windows APIs from Python.

So there is no way, you will get this to work on a non-windows machine